# Conocer tipo de dato recibido por consola en python

Tags: python

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera o método para conocer el tipo de dato recibido por consola en python, ya que lo que se recibe por defecto es String. Que por ejemplo me devuelva int, float o str según el caso:

```
variable = input("12.445")
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con la función `eval` que evalúa una cadena como código python,  pero su uso no es aconsejable.

```py
variable = input("Ingrese algo: ")
tipo = type(eval(variable))
print(tipo)
```

Si quieres hacer esto de forma segura existe el módulo `ast` que proporciona el método `literal_eval`, que solo evalúa expresiones que puedan ser tipos de datos

```py
from ast import literal_eval

variable = input("Ingrese algo: ")
tipo = type(literal_eval(variable))
print(tipo)
```

Lo único que ay que tomar en cuenta es que si queremos un string debemos de ingresar `"hola"`, es decir con las comillas dobles o simples. Siempre es bueno poner un`try/except` para evitar algunos problemas

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que puedes usar algo como esto

```py
    variable = input("12.445")
    try:
        variable = int(variable)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            variable = float(variable)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    print(type(variable))
```

Primero se intenta convertir la variable a tipo entero con `int(variable)`, de no ser posible causa una excepción lo que hará que se intente convertir a tipo flotante `float(variable)`, en caso de que ninguna de las conversiones sea posible se quedara de tipo string que es lo que retorna el input por defecto.

Comment: Por favor explica tu respuesta, lee [answer]

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Y si se ingresa um booleano esto fallará devolviendo un strimg

Comment: Bueno en la pregunta original no hablan de booleanos además creo que la dinámica general esta entendida.
Y luego será "si ingresa una lista retornara un string"